# Pycairo get_data() not working with create_for_rectangle()

Tags: image-processing, pycairo

I have a function that cuts out a shape from an RGBA image by turning the image into a pycairo surface, cutting out the shape from the surface, and then transferring that into a different pycairo surface.

This works properly, as I have tried saving to png to check the images. However, I'd like to use the image in the new pycairo surface as an array.

This is what I tried to do to achieve that:

```py
surface2 = surface.create_for_rectangle(x_min*scale,y_min*scale,width,height)
buf = surface2.get_data()
crop = np.ndarray(shape = (math.ceil(height),math.ceil(width),4), dtype = np.uint8, buffer=buf)
return crop
```

This solution was taken from official pycairo documentation. This would work properly for `surface`, but not with `surface2`. I assumed it had something to do with the `create_for_rectangle()` function. The other solution I thought of is writing `surface2` to png and then using `cv2.imread()` to get it, but that seems crude.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find an answer to `create_for_rectangle()`'s interaction with `get_data()`. As a solution for what I intend to do however, I did this instead:

```py
surface2 = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, round(width), round(height))
ctx2 = cairo.Context(surface2)
ctx2.set_source_surface(surface, -x_min*scale, -y_min*scale)
ctx2.paint()
```

`surface2` now works as intended with `get_data()`, and I am now able to properly get the numpy array associated with `surface2`.